# Нужна библиотека для оплаты в Android

Tags: java, android

Во многих приложениях есть возможность оплачивать деньги через Qiwi, WebMoney, Visa и.т.д. через разные платежные системы, В Android я нашел лишь billing. тобишь встроенную систему платежей гугла.

А как тогда подключают другие разработчкики системы платежей других систем. типо qiwi или visa.

Гугл на все запросы выдает готовые приложения с такой системой. А не то как реализовать разработчику это

Comment: Попробуйте к поисковым запросам добавлять ключевики SDK и/или API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило это активность с WebView с открытой сгенерированной страницей под транзакцию интернет-эквайринга например таких как Yandex Касса. У них есть уже готовое решение в виде SDK под разные платформы, в том числе и Android. 
https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/concepts/kassa-integration-docpage
Не говорю что Яндекс.Касса в данном случае уникальна, вы можете посмотреть и другие банки предоставляющий услугу интернет-эквайринга.

Comment: А для Visa есть такая же sdk? чтобы подключил. добавил фрагмент допустим или пару строчек кода и все заработало. А то на гугле wallet там столько кода что просто убиться можно. Пока поймешь что за что отвечает сутки 3 пройдет

Comment: @xTIGRx интернет-эквайринг это сервис для оплаты товаров или услуг посредством разных способов оплаты, и, как правило, Visa входит в том числе в этот список. Подберите себе услугу интернет-эквайринга в банках, которая бы удовлетворяла вас в комиссии и обслуживании, и стоит потратить время на это, чтобы потом не было больно.

Comment: у Yandex Кассы не работают рекуррентные платежи через мобильные SDK, т.е. если понадобятся - нужно будет писать отдельные костыли через отдельный WebView.